# Pass the maximum key encountered across all mappers as parameter to the next job

Tags: hadoop

I have a chain of Map/Reduce jobs:

Job1 takes data with a time stamp as a key and some data as value and transforms it.

For Job2 I need to pass the maximum time stamp that appears across all mappers in Job1 as a parameter. (I know how to pass parameters to Mappers/Reducers)

I can keep track of the maximum time stamp in each mapper of Job1, but how can I get the maximum across all mappers and pass it as a parameter to Job2?

I want to avoid running a Map/Reduce Job just to determine the maximum time stamp, since the size of my data set is in the terabyte+ scale.

Is there a way to accomplish this using Hadoop or maybe Zookeeper?

Comment: Basically my question is: How can I pass the maximum of all mappers' maxima of the timestamp to the next job (as a parameter)? I could probably use HBase or some other DB, but is there a way to do this in Hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing the following, create a directory where you can put the maximum of each Mapper inside a file that is the mapper name+id. The idea is to have a second output directory and to avoid concurrency issues just make sure that each mapper writes to a unique file. Keep the maximum as a variable and write it to the file on each mappers `cleanup` method.

Once the job completes, it's trivial to iterate over secondary output directory to find the maximum.

Comment: You sure writing to the distributed cache works without glitches? This page http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html says "...the cache files should not be modified by the application or externally while the job is executing."

Comment: I've used it for minimal writes like this in the past (notice it's in cleanup), but according to that I'm just lucky.  I will change my answer though, thanks for pointing that line out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way 2 maps can talk to each other.So a map only job( job1) can not get you global max. timestamp.However,I can think of 2 approaches as below.

I assume your job1 currently is a map only job and you are writing output from map itself.

A. Change your mapper to write the main output using MultipleOutputs and not Context or OutputCollector.Emit additional (key,value) pair as (constant,timestamp) using context.write().This way, you shuffle only the (constant,timestamp) pairs to reducer.Add a reducer that caliculates max. among the values it received.Run  the job, with number of reducers set as 1.The output written from mapper will give you your original output while output written from reducer will give you global max. timestamp.

B. In job1, write the max. timestamp in each mapper as output.You can do this in cleanup().Use MultipleOutputs to write to a folder other than that of your original output.
 Once job1 is done, you have 'x' part files in the output folder assuming you have 'x' mappers in job1.You can do a getmerge on this folder to get all the part files into a single local file.This file will have 'x' lines each contain a timestamp.You can read this using a stand-alone java program,find the global max. timestamp and save it in some local file.Share this file to job2 using distrib cache or pass the global max. as a parameter.